# Is there a specific name for a Markov chain with varying transition probabilities?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Markov chain is characterised by constant transition probabilities. If those transition probabilities change over time, then are they still called Markov chains? If not, what are such entities called?

Comment: They're called non-homogeneous or time-inhomogeneous Markov chains.

Comment: See this MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168398/time-inhomogeneous-markov-chains